# CiviCRM Multi-day Events + Drupal Calendar + Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, civicrm-entity, calendar

How can I show CiviCRM Multi-day events on drupal calendar module (Not fullcalendar), civicrm Entity module and views in drupal 7 ?

I am trying to achieve something like this: https://www.drupal.org/files/images/civicrm_events_calendar.png

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You specifically mention Multi-day events - do you have this working with single day events?

Answer (score 1):

This is available as a CiviCRM extension.

Under the administer tab, click "customise data and screens". You should see a "manage extensions" link - hit that.

In the extensions manager, click on "add new". Look in that list for the calendar, then install it!

If it‘s not in that list for you then please post back including your civi version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @JohnFF. But I am looking for something on the drupal side instead of a CiviCRM based solution.

Comment: Hey, I'm looking for this Multi-day extension in 4.6, but it looks like 4.2 is the last supported version.  Is that right?

Comment: @Peter_ if you want to experiment and contact the coder directly (via github) or post back here that may be best. In general, extensions need updating between 4.2 to 4.6 (the activity structure changed in 4.4) but I don't think it'd be that hard to do.

Comment: Thanks @JohnFF.  I don't think he has this extension on github, although he has other projects there.  I wish I could find a porting guide!